# How to make a HEAD request to Docker Hub API to get the manifest?

Tags: docker, api, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-api

I need to reach manifests of a lot of images on Docker hub, but every GET request for getting manifest is counted as a pull, as a result, I am restricted by the rate limits of docker hub. Is there a way to get the manifest with a HEAD request instead of GET from the API?

Edit: From Docker registry API [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) :

**GET** /v2//manifests/: Fetch the manifest identified by name and reference where reference can be a tag or digest. A HEAD request can also be issued to this endpoint to obtain resource information without receiving all data.

So I assume we can get related information with an HEAD request.

Comment: A `HEAD` request doesn't return any document content, so it's not really going to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell script to do that looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ref="${1:-library/ubuntu:latest}"
sha="${ref#*@}"
if [ "$sha" = "$ref" ]; then
  sha=""
fi
wosha="${ref%%@*}"
repo="${wosha%:*}"
tag="${wosha##*:}"
if [ "$tag" = "$wosha" ]; then
  tag="latest"
fi
apio="application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"
apiol="application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"
apid="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
apidl="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')
curl -H "Accept: ${apio}" -H "Accept: ${apiol}" -H "Accept: ${apid}" -H "Accept: ${apidl}" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -I -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${sha:-$tag}"
```

Note that the head request only shows the headers, and the most useful one is `docker-content-digest` so you can get the digest for a specific tag:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 1416
content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
docker-content-digest: sha256:20fa2d7bb4de7723f542be5923b06c4d704370f0390e4ae9e1c833c8785644c1
docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
etag: "sha256:20fa2d7bb4de7723f542be5923b06c4d704370f0390e4ae9e1c833c8785644c1"
date: Thu, 08 Sep 2022 17:45:42 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
ratelimit-limit: 100;w=21600
ratelimit-remaining: 100;w=21600
docker-ratelimit-source: 68.100.24.47
```

If you want to do this for other registries, you'll need to adjust the authentication. Both go-containerregistry's crane and regclient's regctl tools have image digest commands that handle the authentication and return just the digest.